# r - Retain Index while merging data frame

Tags: r, merge

I am using College dataframe in R. I have the following code

```
input.df = College
# Making df.train similar to input.df but with zero rows. 
df.train = input.df[0,]
temp.split = input.df[input.df[,1] == "Yes",]
sample.size = floor(0.75 * nrow(temp.split))
train.ind = sample(seq_len(nrow(temp.split)),size = sample.size)
temp.train = temp.split[train.ind, ]
df.train = merge(x = df.train, y = temp.train, all = TRUE)
```

After merging I loose the index.

```
head(input.df)
                             Private Apps Accept Enroll Top10perc Top25perc 
Abilene Christian University     Yes 1660   1232    721        23        52   
Adelphi University               Yes 2186   1924    512        16        29            
Adrian College                   Yes 1428   1097    336        22        50            
Agnes Scott College              Yes  417    349    137        60        89             
Alaska Pacific University        Yes  193    146     55        16        44             
Albertson College                Yes  587    479    158        38        62         

head(temp.train, n = 4)
                            Private  Apps Accept Enroll Top10perc Top25perc 
University of South Florida   No  7589   4676   1876        29        63    
Virginia Tech                 No 15712  11719   4277        29        53     
Valley City State University  No   368    344    212         5        27    
Winthrop University           No  2320   1805    769        24        61    

head(df.train)    
      Private Apps Accept Enroll Top10perc Top25perc F.Undergrad P.Undergrad 
1         No  233    233    153         5        12         658          58     
2         No  285    280    208        21        43        1140         473     
3         No  368    344    212         5        27         863         189     
4         No  434    412    319        10        30        1376         237     
5         No  441    369    172        17        45         633         317     
6         No  480    405    380        19        46        1673        1014
```

*The above outputs are truncated to fit in the window*

As you can see "University of South Florida", "Virginia Tech" etc are lost after merging. Is there a way I can retain them?

Comment: We don't see that they are lost... You used `head` one one data frame and `tail` on the other... what is the output of `which(!rownames(temp.train) %in% row names(input.df))`?

Comment: The rownames are not lost in `input.df` and `temp.train`. They are correct but in `df.train` after merging the rownames are lost and replaced by numbers. How do I retain the rownames after merging so that I could see university names in `df.train`?

Comment: How about adding a column `university` to each data frame... Those will retain.

Comment: I don't want `university` to be part of the model. Plus I am trying to write a generic code that I can use in a function to split the input dataset into train and test sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use `merge` like that (i.e. keeping `row.names`).

Note that e.g. `dplyr::left_join()` would actually have the same problem.

I fear you'll have to include the `row.names` temporarily during the `merge`, for example like:

```
df.train = transform(merge(
  x = df.train,
  y = cbind(rownames = rownames(temp.train), temp.train),
  all = TRUE
), row.names = rownames, rownames = NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks very much RonaldASc.